# how to change volume using activity manager (am) in termux

Tags: android, termux, activity-manager

I have android phone with `termu`x app.

I know to open a link from `termux` using the command `am (activity manager)`

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

But now i want to increase or decrease the volume using `am` command

How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use am to open a link you can just use normal

```
xdg-open http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

To open any website from termux.
And for changing the Volume of your android phone in termux you can use Termux api
https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-volume